# Is using a socket connection possible within iOS 7 background fetch mode?

Tags: ios, ios7, tcp, background, fetch

Apple added in iOS 7 new possibility to execute activities in the background, **fetch mode**, which can be used e.g. for Twitter, when frequently small amounts of data need to be downloaded (official description: The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network.),[Apple Document Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)

However, I need to use a TCP connection.

Does anyone know whenever TCP connection may be used in such scenario between the calls?

**The scenario is:**

I open the TCP socket in the beginning and then the application can use it in these fetch calls. Of course handlers are needed when the TCP connection drops, but there is a difference between rare necessity to reconnect and constant (i.e. in each fetch iteration) need to reconnect.